# Irrigation system not working

Tags: irrigation

I recently moved into a house that has an older irrigation system. Picture of the unit below. I've found the manual online and I believe of got the unit to work. However, nothing happens at the fountains. Nothing. The machine's LCD status indicates that it's going but nothing happens.

I've never had an irrigation system so I know nothing about them. What might I be doing wrong. Could it be that some tap is closed somewhere that means the system isn't getting any water supply? If so, are these taps usually inside or outside?

Any help appreciated![image: Richdel irrigation control]

Comment: Irrigation systems are usually blown-out and the water turned off for the winter.  You should find out from the former owner if they did this before winter and who they hired.  Turning it back on in the spring is usually done as part of the package and no charge to you.  If it wasn't blown-out (all water removed from lines) and you managed to turn it on, you might have broken pipes and lose lots of water...flood your basement, whatever. If you don't have winters go look near your water meter, there should be a backflow valve and a way to turn the water on to irrigation.

Comment: Make sure you check out who winterized your system...there is a valuable warranty you could lose if you turn the water on yourself...